# Batch file for moving file to not yet exist folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder - `PHOTOS` with a structure like this:

```
image_001.png
image_002.png
image_003.png
image_004.png
image_005.png
image_006.png
image_007.png
and more.....
```

I want to move the first two-images in `PHOTOS` folder to a subfolder (ex: `PHOTOS_SUB001`) and if the number of images in `PHOTOS` folder is 3, move all remain images to the last subfolder.

In my examples:

`image_001` and `image_002` will be moved to `PHOTOS_SUB001` folder
`image_003` and `image_004` will be moved to `PHOTOS_SUB002` folder
`image_005`, `image_006` and `image_007` will be moved to `PHOTOS_SUB003` folder

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Please learn, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). StackOverFlow is not a code writing or code teaching service.

Comment: You need to learn this for yourself. What's the good in us telling you how to do it? We're here to guide you, not to do it for you. At what point would you have thought critically about the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get the total count of files to move,
- iterate files and count,
- calculate the rest and check if uneven.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\12\14\SO_53784108.cmd
@Echo off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Base=A:\PHOTOS"
PushD "%Base%" || (Echo can't find Base:%Base% &Pause&Goto :Eof)

:: get Total files
For /f %%A in ('dir /B *.png ^|find /c ".png"') Do set "Total=%%%A"

Set Cnt=0
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B *.png') Do (
    Set /A "Cnt+=1,Rest=Total-Cnt+(Cnt%%2),DstNum=1000+(Cnt+1)/2"
    Set "Dest=%Base%\PHOTOS_SUB!DstNum:~-3!"
    MD "!Dest!" 2>Nul
    If !Rest! lss 2 (
        Move "%Base%\*.png" "!Dest!\" >Nul
        Goto :End
    ) else (
        Move "%%A" "!Dest!\" >Nul
    )
)
:End
PopD
Goto :Eof
```

Sample Tree after running the batch:

```
> Tree \ /F
└───PHOTOS
    ├───PHOTOS_SUB001
    │       image_001.png
    │       image_002.png
    │
    ├───PHOTOS_SUB002
    │       image_003.png
    │       image_004.png
    │
    └───PHOTOS_SUB003
            image_005.png
            image_006.png
            image_007.png
```